# Calculating the probability a predicted point is 0

Tags: probability, bayesian, prediction, gaussian-process

I have a deterministic function $f(x)$ and have evaluated some points $x_1,...,x_n$.  So essentially I have pairs of data $(x_1,f(x_1)),...,(x_n,f(x_n))$.  I am modeling the function $f(x)$ using a Gaussian process and thus can make predictions about the function where I do not have observed values.

For example, imagine I have the following data (black points) coming from the true function (black line) and I try to predict the true function (red line) using my Gaussian process.

[image]

So now, what I am interested in is using my Gaussian process to make my best guess at where the true function $f(x)$ will be equal to 0. So what I am interested in is probably making a calculation that would look something like

$$\text{Pr}(f(x)=0)=...?$$

So my questions are:

1. What are the possible ways to quantify how likely a predicted point
   is equal to zero under this modeling scenario?
2. Is that probability calculation feasible?

Also, if it matters, I am doing this from a Bayesian point-of-view.

Comment: For most $x$, the chance that $f(x)=0$ must be zero. The nearest I can guess to what you're trying to ask concerns how to construct a subset $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathbb{R}$ based on the data. Your prior, your model of the data, and your statistical assumptions about how $f$ is related to the data make this a *random* set, so you could try to construct a short $\mathcal{I}$ with a high chance that $f(\mathcal{I})$ includes $0$. Would this be an accurate interpretation?

Comment: @whuber yes I think that is a good way to think about it. I basically want to be able to predict at a large number of points and quantify how likely any of those predicted points are to being equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_i=f(x_i)$ and that your interest is in predicting $\tilde{y} = f(\tilde{x})$. From a Bayesian perspective, you want the posterior predictive distribution for $\tilde{y}$, namely
$$ p(\tilde{y}|y) = \int p(\tilde{y}|y,\theta)p(\theta|y) d\theta$$
where $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ and $\theta$ is the parameters of the Gaussian process. Since you have assumed a Gaussian process, the conditional distribution $p(\tilde{y}|y,\theta)$ is normal.

The marginal distribution $p(\tilde{y}|y)$ is continuous* and thus $Pr(\tilde{y}=0|y) = 0$. One way to answer your question is to see if this distribution has density near zero. If you are interested in single number summaries, then you could calculate $Pr(\tilde{y}<0|y)$. If this is near 0.5, then 0 is a reasonable value while if this is near 0 or 1, then 0 is not a reasonable value.

*It is unlikely that this marginal distribution can be computed exactly and you will likely end up simulating from the distribution by simulating $\theta$ from its posterior and then simulating $\tilde{y}$ conditional on the simulated values for $\theta$. Then you can calculate the quantities above using simulations.

Comment: This is idea makes sense to me.  Would I have to just use my "best judgement" as to what close to 0.5 is?

Comment: Also would it make sense to calculate $$Pr(-\epsilon < \tilde y < \epsilon )$$ for some very small epsilon near zero.

Comment: The $\epsilon$ approach won't work very well because it will be sensitive to the value of $\epsilon$ that is chosen (as $\epsilon \to 0$ this probability will converge to zero) and the shape of the density for $\tilde{y}$ (as the density gets flatter, the probability will get smaller). So I would suggest the tail probability instead. Yes, you will have to use your best judgement which will depend why you are making this decision.